# Phusion Passenger, mod_rails rails 2.3 problem

Tags: passenger, mod-rails, phusion

"The application has exited during startup (i.e. during the evaluation of config/environment.rb). The error message may have been written to the web server's log file. Please check the web server's  log file (i.e. not the (Rails) application's log file) to find out why the application exited."

I'm getting the above error message when I try to access my test site.

Permission for config/* is

-rw-r--r--  1 www-data root 2011 Aug 27 20:17 environment.rb
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root 4096 Aug 27 20:17 environments
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root 4096 Aug 27 20:17 initializers
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root 4096 Aug 27 20:17 locales
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root 2431 Aug 27 20:17 routes.rb

I've tried "root root 2011 Aug 27 20:17 environment.rb" as well but no success either.

I'm running Debian GNU/Linux and have other Rails sites running fine on the same server, I have tried to replicate the setup from one of the other sites, but it's not having any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this same issue, and after killing passenger and apache ended up finding:
http://geminstallthat.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/passenger-with-rails-23-application-missingsourcefile/

Essentially the issue is for some versions of libapache2-mod-passenger the app/controllers/application.rb change to app/controllers/application_controller.rb (in Rails 2.3) explodes things (technical term).